# Hibernate - How to get single value from another table without primary/Foreign key relationship?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables(Employee & Department).

**Employee**(ID, employee name, dept id, employee address) --> ID primary key

**Department**(ID, department name, address) --> ID primary key

**Note:** Consider no primary key / foreign key relationship between these 2 tables

**Now based on dept id in Employee, i need to fetch its corresponding dept name from  Department & display it in Employee.**

Employee(ID, employee name, dept id(Display dept name instead of dept id, query department table to get dept name through passing dept id), employee address)

What are all possible ways to achieve this?

Regards
Raj

Comment: What is the reason of there's no foreign key on those tables?

Comment: I mentioned employee and department for easy understanding. In actual scenario we save only ID in master table and will fetch its corresponding VALUE from lookup table. This lookup table is common. Multiple table get values from this table passing id.

Comment: Please update and clarify your question as this does not seem to be a JPA but rather a JSON serialization problem.

Comment: The fact that it isn't a foreign key constraint, doesn't mean you cannot map it as an `@ManyToOne`.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least three possible solutions:

1. Create a "normal" SQL query for this, joins can be perfectly done without a PK/FK-relationship.
2. Perform two SQL queries: One query for fetching the employee, then extract the ID and then a second query to fetch the department by ID.
3. Change your JPA entities to include the relationship as you would normally do having a `@OneToMany` relationship so you can load the employee with its department as usual. Same as 1 applies, joins (whether done by you or by the JPA provider) don't need a PK/FK-relationship.

Whilst 1 can be done with plain SQL, 2 can be done using the entity manager without the need to write "plain" SQL. 3 would be the easiest solution, obviously.

Comment: Thanks. Just i need a single value. I mentioned employee and department for easy understanding. In real case, i do have table with more than 20 columns and out of which, in 10 columns we save only ID. Will fetch its corresponding VALUE from multiple lookup tables. These lookup table are common. Multiple table get values from this table passing id. Is't a effective way of using normal SQL query ? wont it impact the performance. Could you share any example?

Comment: What keeps you from writing a SQL query that joins your master table with multiple lookup tables for each ID? It's the same as you would write a PK/FK-supported join.

Comment: If SQL query i could get as read only data. Hope i could not update back to db. I want to fetch all these data to display in UI & also it must be updatable when user clicks save button. That's why interested to achieve this using ENTITIES rather than using native SQL. I'm new to this technology. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Just as I wrote - JPA entities don't need no FK/PK-relationship at all to model your database structure as entities.

Comment: It must be @OneToOne, let say one dept_id has only one dept_name. I need response as 
{
"id": 10,
"employee_name": "yxz",
"dept_id": 100,
"department_name": "Maths" 
}

and not as below response,

{
"id": 10,
"employee_name": "yxz",
"dept_id": 100,
"department": {
  "department_name": "Maths" 
 }
}

Comment: What does modeling this as JPA entities has to do with your JSON serialization?

Comment: Modeling JPA entities gets me response as(parent, child row) which causing problem in showing data in UI. In simple, in addition to dept_id in Employee, I need another attribute to display dept_name. I dont want child row in response. Hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, so why don't you simply change your JSON mapper?

Comment: Ok. Thanks will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can `@Query` in repository and write your JPA query using JOIN.

**Sample Query:**

```
@Query( value = "select new map(employee.name as empName, employee.id as id, department.id as depId, department.name as depName) from Employee employee INNER JOIN Department department ON employee.depId = department.id where employee.id = :id" )
public Map<String,Object> getEmployeeById(long id);
```